# Struggling to count multiple targets in a grid in Python

Tags: python, grid, iteration, border, cell

`So, I'm struggling on a certain python problem. Essentially, the user can input a grid of any size, and also the locations of targets on the grid. I have to write a program to iterate over all of the border cells, and find the best location to place a certain type of arrow, so it hits the most targets without encountering an empty cell. This is the problem below:

Given an nxn grid  with target locations and with empty border cells, find which arrow when placed in a border cell would hit the most consectuive targets. A = left, B = up, C = right, D = down, E = Diagonally right upwards, F = Diagonally left upwards, G = Diagonally right downwards, H = Diagonally left downwards. Output the location and the position of the arrow as a 3 character string. The upper left corner is identified as row = 0, column = 0 in row major order.

Make a function with 2 parameters: A number, size(for example 2 = 2x2), representing the side of the grid and a string, targets, representing the locations of the targets as two character strings each seperated by a single space.

The function should return a 3-character string representing the location and the direction of the arrow that would hit the most targets without encountering an empty cell. And in the case of a tie, output the string that comes first in order by ASCII Coes(e.g. "05F" < "50A")

CONSTRAINTS:

The inputted number will be no more than 10. The locations of the targets will all be on the grid and not in any border cells.

P.S. The x and Y axis's are flipped for this question.

```py
## FUNCTION INPUT ##

def FindArrowAI(grid_size, targets):
    
    target_list = []
    target_lis = targets.split()

    arrow_list = []
    
    for z in target_lis:
        target_list.append(str(z))

    block_list = []

    count = 0

    size = [[0] * grid_size for _ in range(grid_size)]
    border_cells = []

    # Iterate over the cells in the size
    for i in range(grid_size):
        for j in range(grid_size):
            # Check if the current cell is on the border
            if i == 0 or i == grid_size - 1 or j == 0 or j == grid_size - 1:
                cell_coords = str(i) + str(j)  # Convert indices to strings and concatenate them
                border_cells.append(cell_coords)

    ## BLOCK IDENTIFICATION ##
    
    for block_y in range(0, grid_size, 1):
        for block_x in range(0, grid_size, 1):
            block_list.append(str(block_y) + str(block_x))
    for x in target_list:
        block_list.remove(x)


    ## TARGET IDENTIFICATION ##
    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) + 0) + str(int(i[1]) - 1) in target_list:
            loc_a = str(int(i[0]) + 0) + str(int(i[1]) + 1)
            if loc_a in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_a) + "A")
                
    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 0) in target_list:
            loc_b = str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 0)
            if loc_b in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_b) + "B")
            
    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) + 0) + str(int(i[1]) + 1) in target_list:
            loc_c = str(int(i[0]) + 0) + str(int(i[1]) - 1)
            if loc_c in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_c) + "C")

    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 0) in target_list:
            loc_d = str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 0)
            if loc_d in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_d) + "D")

    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) - 1) in target_list:
            loc_e = str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 1)
            if loc_e in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_e) + "E")

    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 1) in target_list:
            loc_f = str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) -1)
            if loc_f in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_f) + "F")
            
    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 1) in target_list:
            loc_g = str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) - 1)
            if loc_g in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_g) + "G")

    for i in target_list:
        if str(int(i[0]) + 1) + str(int(i[1]) - 1) in target_list:
            loc_h = str(int(i[0]) - 1) + str(int(i[1]) + 1)
            if loc_h in border_cells:
                arrow_list.append(str(loc_h) + "H")
    print(arrow_list)
    print(target_list)
  
FindArrowAI(5, "31 21 13 32 11 12")
```

For this test case, the expected output was supposed to be 01D. So far, I just made my code output every possible location for an arrow to hit 2 targets, but I need to check which location can hit the most, because one location might be able to hit 3, or 4 targets even. This is what I need help on, so if anyone can explain it to me and help me out with my code, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the question is verbose, please reduce to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   in particular, the actual error that you are getting.  Or an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: also, as an extra part,  from the reading of the question.  Structurally, it appears as though there should be at least 2 functions.  [1] scan the border, [2] place a certain type of arrow....